# referring to specific parts of a python dictionary in javascript

Tags: javascript, python, python-2.7, flask

I made a program which parses data and then does a python `json.dumps()` with it. Next, in my javascript, I did a jQuery `getJSON()` with this data.
Before I did the `json.dumps()` with my data, I split it into three list because I didn't know how to deal with the data in js. The data is structured like this:

```
Key: (value1, value2)
```

I simply need to refer to those individual 'columns' in my javascript separately. I feel like it might be more efficient to just do the `dumps()` with the python dictionary but I don't know how to refer to it as I want in the javascript. Obviously it's important that the data stay "grouped"

How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Can you please give more elaborate example of the data you are dumping and how do you want to refer in javascript?

Comment: It sounds like you know what to do, you just need to read up on how to access values in JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a full example that I have used in a mapping project. Javascript loads data via Ajax from the flask application.

The JQuery ajax method is very similar to the getJSON method.

```
#ajax method to retreive well data for dynamic well values, x_pos, y_pos, substance concentration
@app.route('/getWellData', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def getWellData():
    #get all samples with that date
    date_collected = request.args.get('date_collected')
    site_id = request.args.get('site_id')
    site_map_id = request.args.get('site_map_id')
    substance_id = request.args.get('substance_id')

    well_results = wellSubstanceDataBySite(
        site_id=site_id,
        site_map_id=site_map_id,
        date_collected=date_collected,
        substance_id=substance_id)

    #return json to updateMarks ajax javascript function
    return json.dumps(well_results)
```

Javascript:

```
//call the ajax endpoint for getWellData to return position, values, etc
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: '/getWellData',
    data: data,
    success: function(data){

        //iterate over each value in the data array and append it as div element to the .landmarks div
        $.each(data, function(well_id, well){

            //create the mark element, must be all mashed into one line, wont work with multiple lines
            //sutract depth_of_water (well.value) from well.top_of_casing
            var goundwater_elevation_val = well.top_of_casing - well.value
            var mark = '<div class="item mark" id="well-' + well_id + '" data-id="' + well_id + '" data-position="' + well.xpos + "," + well.ypos + '" data-value="' + goundwater_elevation_val.toFixed(4) + '" data-show-at-zoom="0"><div><div class="text"><input class="well-checkboxes" type="checkbox" name="enable-well-' + well_id + '" checked style="margin:3px;"><strong>' + goundwater_elevation_val.toFixed(4) + '</strong></div><img src="/static/jquery-image-viewer/example/images/mark.png" width="50px" height="50px" alt="Permanent Mark" /></div></div>';
            if (well.value != 0) {
                //append the new mark to the .landmarks div
                $('.landmarks').append(mark);
            }

        });

        //refresh all landmarks to plot the new landmarks on the map with the smoothZoom API
        $('#sitemap').smoothZoom('refreshAllLandmarks');
    }
});
```